# keyword extraction and Keyword based text classification

Tags: deep-learning, keyword, feature-extraction, text-classification, keyword-extraction

Currently i am working on a project which requires keywords extraction or we can say keyword based text classification . The dataset contains 3 columns text, keywords and cc terms, I need to extract keywords from text and then classify the text based on those keywords, each row in dataset has their own keywords, i want to extract similar kind of keywords. I want to train the by providing text and keyword column so that the model is able to extract keywords for unknown text.please help

[image: image contains dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword extraction is typically done using [TF-IDF scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) simply by setting a score threshold. When training a classifier, it does not make much sense to cut off the keywords at a certain threshold, knowing that something is not likely to be a keyword might also be a valuable piece of information for the classifier.

The simplest way to get the TF-IDF scores for particular words is using [TfIdfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in scikit-learn that does all the laborious text preprocessing steps (tokenization, removing stop words).

You can probably achieve better results by fine-tuning BERT for your classification task (but of course at the expense of much higher computational costs).

Comment: Please, if you thing the answer is correct, mark it so, so others also know that this post answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, it has helped me lot in understanding the concept